# AVPlayer size changes in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am Using AVPlayerViewController here in portrait mode it looks fine but when i change the orientation to landscape mode the player gets too small it look like single tool bar. How can i fix the player size in both portrait mode and in landscape mode and it should be flexible when the device size also changes or can we fix it to the screen centre so the little size difference won't matter if played on bigger device size 6s Plus.

```
NSString *localfilepath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[managedObject valueForKey:@"clip_path"]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[localfilepath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,80,controller.view.frame.size.height+(self.view.frame.size.width/1.6),self.view.frame.size.width/1.2);

controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
//player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;
//  [player pause];
[player play];
```